# Running teleop in Safety Mode on Turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, teleop, keyboard-teleop, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I use teleop in Safety Mode? Right now teleop switches the Create automatically to Full Mode.

(I would like to use Turtlebot for telepresence. It would be nice when the teleoperator couldn't drive the robot down the stairs, even when the connection drops or lags)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12596/running-teleop-in-safety-mode-on-turtlebot/) by [Robert Buzink](https://answers.ros.org/users/1627/robert-buzink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have filed a ticket here: https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/122 to add a parameter to change the default

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Buzink](https://answers.ros.org/users/1627/robert-buzink/) on 2012-02-12**:
Thanks! Could you give me a rough estimate on where in the code I should look to change the default myself in the meantime? (Is it in turtlebot_key.cpp or somewhere in cmd_vel?)

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-02-16**:
you;ll need to edit the turtlebot_node and turtlebot_driver code to get it to run in safe mode